# How to get the title? From this XML using Zend framework?

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, xpath

I am very new to Zend Framework. And i have tried to get the XML value but cant make it work.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result count="2">
    <blocks>
        <listing>
            <title>Title 1</title>
            <id>1</id>
        </listing>
        <listing>
            <title>Title 2</title>
            <id>2</id>
        </listing>

    </blocks>
</result>
```

PHP (to find all the title):

```
    $dom = new Zend_Dom_Query();
    $dom->setDocumentXml($result);

    $results = $dom->queryXpath('/result/blocks/listing/title'); 
    //$dom->queryXpath('/*/*/listing'); no luck
    //$dom->queryXpath('///listing'); no luck 

    foreach($results as $k)
    {
        Zend_Debug::dump($k->getAttribute('title')); // empty
        echo $k->getDocument(); // shows none
    }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `queryXpath('/result/blocks/listing/title')` your `$k` already *is* the [DOMElement](http://docs.php.net/domelement) that represents the `<tile>...</title>` elements.
You can retrieve the value via $k[->nodeValue](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue). For a [DOMElement](http://docs.php.net/domelement) that's the concatenation of all text nodes in the [descendant axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes).

```
foreach($results as $k)
{
    Zend_Debug::dump($k->nodeValue); // empty
}
```

Comment: queryXpath('/result/blocks/listing') then also i can get $k->nodeValue? How can i get $k->title->nodeValue or $k->id->nodeValue

Comment: With SimpleXML you can use the `$parent->child` syntax, see http://docs.php.net/SimpleXML

Answer (score 0):

title is a node - not an attribute - attributes are placed inside the tag :)